# Images not displaying on web page in simple Spring Boot application

Tags: html, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm trying to load a basic homepage just to try out Spring Boot and the images are not being loaded.

I've tried all sorts of different URL combinations to check whether the class path is wrong. Earlier I had an images folder within the static folder but this did not work either. I've removed adblock extensions, I've tried on both Firefox and Chrome browsers, I inspected the elements on the page for the image path and the response header. I have added no configuration to application.properties. I tried with and without the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation as per  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-auto-configuration

The one thing I noticed was that the GET requests are all returning 200OK, as opposed to 404, and the type on the network tab is listed as text/html, whereas the Spring icon image used in the webpage title is listed as image/x-icon, but I don't know if that's the issue.

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping
    public String home2() {

        return "home2";
    }

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PuppR Home</title>
</head>
<body>


<h1>Homepage</h1>

<img src="jpx10.jpg"/>
<img src="/jpx10.jpg"/>
<img src="static/jpx10.jpg"/>
<img src="/static/jpx10.jpg"/>
<img src="../static/jpx10.jpg"/>
<img src="/../static/jpx10.jpg"/>


</body>
</html>
```

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I'm including links to images of my project structure as I don't have enough reputation to post images

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOUdg.png

an image of  the actual webpage generated with broken links, and the network console

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dNzY.png

Comment: Where you placed these images?

Comment: /Users/pagoda/spring-workspace/puppR/src/main/resources/static

is the output of pwd for the image file

Comment: If the answer is useful for you give up-vote that will be helpful for others too.

Comment: unfortunately it's not, I have no images directory as shown in my project directory tree

Comment: I have update my code check this

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `<img src="../static/jpx10.jpg" width="1000" th:src="@{/jpx10.jpg}"/>`

Comment: sadly still does not work, you can see in my code that I have tried with that URL path already

Comment: Hello in thymeleaf you have to use th:src it should work I already tested this code.